# Why multiplying two matrices need opposite order compared to its visual apply order in transform matrix

Tags: ios, matrix, uiview, transform, calayer

I am [reading a book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920044352.do) that talks about the iOS UIView transform property and noticed this fact in the picture when using `CGAffineTransformConcat` function, from the documents `CGAffineTransformConcat` simply multiplying its two parameters but here if you want to get Figure 1-9, your transform matrix parameter need in opposite order

[image]

this cause me confused and after a bit searching found [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Composing_and_inverting_transformations) said this

> In other words, the matrix of the combined transformation A followed by B is simply the product of the individual matrices. Note that the multiplication is done in the opposite order from the English sentence: the matrix of "A followed by B" is BA, not AB.

I am not really understand this, because from my current knowledge the Matrix is not commutative but can associate so if the original coordinate is multiplied from the right everything is explainable like this

```
let X = original coordinate
first multiply A --> A*X
then B           --> B*(A*X)
equal            === (B*A)*X
here the final combined matrix BA's order is opposite!
```

but from the apple documents the original coordinate is multiplied from left
[image]

can someone explain this, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Think of it like this:
  where will you place your vector x (assuming coordinates are represented using columnar vectors) which has to transformed? You place it in the last i.e. BAx . So first B(Ax) and then (B(Ax)). So basically you are applying A first and then B.

In ios, instead of representing coordinates as columnar vectors they are using row vectors. Therefore the change in the order of multiplications.

Note:-If you take transpose on both sides, you can observe that it gives the other representation.

```
Suppose x is a column vector.
Text book method = BAx
Lets take its transpose

transpose(B*A*x) = transpose(x) * transpose(B*A)

                 = transpose(x) * transpose(B*A)

                 = transpose(x) * (transpose(A) * transpose(B))

                 = transpose(x) * transpose(A) * transpose(B)

rewriting transpose(A) as A' and transpose(B) as B'

                 = transpose(x) * A' * B'   

                 = ios notation
```

If we use M in one representation then we must use transpose(M) in the other representation.
See page 5 in this https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~fussell/courses/cs384g/lectures/lecture07-Affine.pdf

Try to relate tx and ty in both representations. 
**Columnar representation** (From wiki)
[image: Columnar representation]
**Row representation** (From the question)
[image: Row representation]

Comment: but like I said in the question the apple documents seams like multiplying X from left

Comment: i have updated my answer. generally we use vector in columnar representation. in ios they are using row representation. If you take transpose on both sides. you will see the magic. hope it helps

Comment: actually I have thought of the transpose thing, but it's not like that, because in the matrix you can set tx element which affect x translation, if multiply from right this tx element should sit at the right top corner when supplied to function parameters, but in practice I set this element at left bottom corner and assign to transform property to make translation

Comment: you cannot use the same matrix in both. if you use A in one then you have to use transpose(A) in the other. let me try to find a link for you.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Other_kinds_of_transformations for columnar vector representation

Comment: https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~fussell/courses/cs384g/lectures/lecture07-Affine.pdf ... page 5 and 18. u can compare page 18 content with the image you showed for ios from apple docs. It is just change of representation using either column or row. Since you have shared the translation matrix, try to compare matrices in these representations. You will see that both are same except one is transpose of other

Comment: thanks your effort, but the really confused thing here is in contrast to (x*A)*B --> x*(A*B) what I actually supplied parameter here is (B*A) which lead to x*(B*A), both A and B's tx element is at left bottom corner, your link can't solve this

Comment: why are you supplying BA, you should be supplying AB because coordinates are represented in row vector as per ios diagram. If you want we can chat to discuss this out